# Сортировка Dictionary на основе вложенного Dictionary Item в VBA

Tags: excel, сортировка, словари, vba

Есть сэмпл данных в Excel (таблица):

[image]

Пытаюсь получить ТОП-3 элемента списка на основании "**Salary**" и ТОП-3 на основании "**Revenue**" программно в VBA.

---

В **Visual Basic (VBA)** создал словарь с параметром Name в качестве **Key** и вложенного Dictionary в качестве **Item**.

Вложенный Dictionary имеет параметры "`Salary`", "`Revenue`" and "`Position`" как **Key**. И соответствующие значения из таблицы как **Items**.

Создал **Dictionary**:

```
Dim MainDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim NestedDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    
Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = wsMainWorkSheet.Range("B2:E8")

Dim rowCounter As Long
  
For rowCounter = 1 To rngRange.Rows.Count
    Set NestedDict = New Dictionary
    NestedDict.Add key:="Salary", Item:=rngRange(rowCounter, 2)
    NestedDict.Add key:="Revenue", Item:=rngRange(rowCounter, 3)
    NestedDict.Add key:="Position", Item:=rngRange(rowCounter, 4)
    
    Dim mainKey As String
    mainKey = CStr(rngRange(rowCounter, 1))
    If MainDict.Exists(mainKey) = False Then
        MainDict.Add key:=mainKey, Item:=NestedDict
    Else:
        MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Salary") = MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Salary") + rngRange(rowCounter, 2)
        MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Revenue") = MainDict.Item(mainKey)("Salary") + rngRange(rowCounter, 3)
    End If
Next rowCounter
```

---

Для печати элементов словаря `MainDict` использую такой код:

```
Sub PrintDictionary(dict As Dictionary)
Dim key As Variant, subKey As Variant

For Each key In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print vbNewLine; "Name: " & key
    For Each subKey In dict(key).Keys
        Debug.Print subKey & ": " & dict(key)(subKey)
    Next subKey
Next key
End Sub
```

**Результат:**

> Name: Name1
> Salary: 400
> Revenue: 5000
> Position: Manager

> Name: Name2
> Salary: 500
> Revenue: 25000
> Position: Associate

*(первые две строки)*

---

Сложность в проведении сортировки словаря на основе вложенного словаря:

- Получение ТОП-3 элементов списка (`MainDict`) на основании наибольшего показателя "**Salary**" во вложенном словаре `NestedDict` .
- Получение ТОП-3 элементов списка (`MainDict`) на основании наибольшего показателя "**Revenue**" во вложенном словаре `NestedDict` .

Может ли кто подсказать как это реализовать без ручной предварительной сортировки самих данных в таблице Excel?

***Book1.xlsm** (сэмпл данных) доступен в DropBox: [Book1.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ecor8lt5ynq1crk6m8lqs/Book1.xlsm?rlkey=mi7d8bdfyxamynkiskghdn96j&dl=0)*

Comment: Встроенных в VBA методов сортировки, кроме как на листе Excel, нет. Можно использовать, например, любой из представленных здесь методов сортировки: https://micro-solution.ru/excel/vba/sorting-algorithm